# How to use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, warnings

I have a compile error in my simple MFC window application generated from wizard with several lines of code:

> error C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, **use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS**. See online help for details.

I set `Configuration Properties>>C/C++>>Preprocessor>>Preprocessor Definitions>> _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS`

But this doesn't help. I have another very close project that generates only warning in this place and it has no `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS` definition.

The only difference between the projects is several different options in wizard.

Why does `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS` not help in the first project and why does the second project compile without problems without this definition?

Comment: Did you try with _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS ?

Comment: may be your project in Visual Studio has a "treat warnings as errors" option enabled.

Comment: *Read the error message*

Comment: "treat warnings as errors" is set to No (/WX-)

Comment: yes, I could use strncpy_s, but why another project has no problems wit that?

Comment: These type problems are a classic example of why it is important to learn to build from the command line to familiarize yourself with what options your code need to compile before jumping to the IDE where a bulk of the time you spend troubleshooting problems is simply where is that option buried in VSCode?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Add by

> Configuration Properties>>C/C++>>Preporocessor>>Preprocessor
>   Definitions>> _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

[image: screenshot of the relevant config interface]

Comment: try using the /GS- flag

Comment: I don't see this dialog in Visual Studio 2019 :-(

Comment: sometimes, you enter the settings on x64 Plateform, but the default plateform you are working on is x86. So no effect, frustrating...

Comment: I found @kmcnamee solution much easier. Just go into C/C++ >> General project properties and turn of the SDL setting. Super simple.

Comment: Typo - "Preporocessor" should be "Preprocessor"

Answer (score 97):

Under "Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions" add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Answer (score 33):

If your are in Visual Studio 2012 or later this has an additional setting 'SDL checks' Under  Property Pages -> C/C++ -> General

> Additional Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) recommended checks; includes enabling additional secure code generation features and extra security-relevant warnings as errors.

It defaults to YES - For a reason, I.E you should use the secure version of the strncpy.  If you change this to NO you will not get a error when using the insecure version.

[SDL checks in vs2012 and later](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx)

Comment: "I.E you should use the secure version of the strncpy." just FYI, the secure versions that the SDL checks are recommending seem to be [not portable to other OSes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858252/alternatives-to-ms-strncpy-s), which would make them not suitable for cross platform development. It looks like you would have to disable this check for programs that target more than just windows.

Comment: *you should use the secure version* No.  It's not portable at all.  [**Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations): "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ....  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Comment: Nevermind it's not even clear the "secure" versions are [more secure anyway](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#handler), and the entire "more secure" API is [inherently multithread-**un**safe](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#thrsafe).

Answer (score 29):

For a quick fix or test, I find it handy just adding `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to the top of the file before all #include

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include ...
int main(){
    //...
}
```

Comment: why does `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` need to go above `#include?`

Comment: @cal17_hogo It depends on what's in the headers that are `#include`d. If the headers don't depend on anything that requires `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, then the `#define` can go after the `#include`s.

Comment: @Keith The headers are what causes the compiler to emit the warnings. If you declare the function manually, there s no warning/error. So if you get the warning the define *must* go before the header. Here, it's `_Check_return_ _CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE(ctime_s)` in time.h, together with `#ifdef _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`... earlier

Answer (score 12):

Adding `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to *Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions* didn't work for me, don't know why.

The following hint works: 
In stdafx.h file, please add

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
```

before include other header files.

Answer (score 7):

**Visual Studio 2019** with **CMake**

Add the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
```

Comment: Or per target: `target_compile_definitions(myTarget PRIVATE _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in Visual Studio 2017 and to fix it just added `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` after `#include "pch.h"`

```
#include "pch.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
....
```

Answer (score 0):

the _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS addition to the preprocessor settings worked great for "gets" warnings and this is on an ancient version of Visual C++ 6.0 before Visual Studio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this code works with me (I am using Visual Studio 2022 IDE):

```
// put me on your main.cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).