# What does the error C4996 mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is a simple C++ code:

```
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char str[80];
    cout << "輸入字串：";
    gets(str);
    cout << "輸入的字串：" << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling it, I get the following error:

> "错误1  error C4996: 'gets': This function or variable may be unsafe.
>
> Consider using gets_s instead. To disable deprecation, 
>           use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details."

Comment: It means that "gets" may be unsafe and you should consider using gets_s instead. Or you can define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to disable the warning. You can find more details somewhere in the online help, probably by searching for "C4996" or "gets".

Comment: when  i using gets_s() function instead of gets(). it is OK!

Comment: `gets` is so dangerous that it has been deprecated both in C and in C++

Comment: What is it that makes `gets()` dangerous anyway?

Comment: `gets()` is dangerous because there's no way to protect against a buffer overflow.

Comment: As a courtesy to readers, it would be much better to put messages in English in sample code inside questions on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use use \_CRT\_SECURE\_NO\_WARNINGS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450423/how-to-use-use-crt-secure-no-warnings)

Comment: @Darkrifts [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714)

Comment: 1) try to google error code before you pose your question. 2) please code in english, this can help people who try to help you. 3) In your question, you should give the infos below: a) what you have done; b) what you don't understand; If you just pose a question and ask why but you didn't even try yourself, people will downvote. In this question, we hope see something like: "I have google error C4996 but I don't understand ..."

Comment: @Yves thanks for your advice， and always sorry my poor English！ 1）it is hard for Google in China and  Baidu always tell me something without work. and follow Michael Burr point I  have  read the book  C programing Language，
gets() is dangerous because there's no way to protect against a buffer overflow

Comment: @march_seven When you want to pose a question here, you must make sure that you have tried your best. A question like this is telling us that you just get an error then you pose a question here but you've never tried to solve it by yourself. This is why you get three down-votes. Even Baidu can tell you lots of stuff: http://blog.csdn.net/u013409439/article/details/46911765

Comment: 如果你是刚学c语言，而且你的英语不太好的话，百度是够用的。我的经验是：csdn的论坛不太好用，提问题经常没人回答，但是csdn的博文是不错的，现在还有博客园，这个也很好。提问的话，找c语言的qq群，还有百度贴吧的c语言吧，都有大量的人在上面讨论问题。反正不管你在哪里，一定更要避免“遇到问题立刻找别人问”，一定要有自己思考的过程（在stackoverflow上提问就必须要把自己思考的过程体现在问题里否则会给你downvote），否则你永远学不会编程。一般你只要把编译器的报错信息直接百度搜索一下，大部分问题还是可以找到的。

Comment: @Yves 好的 感谢你的建议.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In genuine [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) or C++14 the correct way to read an entire line is [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) or [std::basic_istream::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Also, you'll better flush the output before reading an input; remember that C++ and C standard IO functions are [buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer).

The old [C89 `gets`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output#gets) function is deprecated since a long time (probably more than ten years), and now forbidden because it is so **dangerous** (can't avoid a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)). So please forget it (in C99 or C11, use [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, on POSIX with C99 or C11, use [getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html); in C++11 or C++14 use as I said [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) or [std::basic_istream::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)).

Your `main`'s body should be:

```
string str;
cout << "輸入字串：" << flush;
getline(cin,str);
cout << "輸入的字串：" << str << endl;
return 0;
```

The advantage of using a `std::string` is that your user could input an arbitrarily long line (up to implementation limits, perhaps million of characters).

If you are coding on a POSIX system like MacOSX or Linux, you could use the [GNU readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) library and function (see also [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)) when reading on a [terminal](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/). The big advantage is that your user is given editing ability (and completion) when typing his line.

<sup>PS. General hint when programming: **read the documentation** of every function that you are using before coding.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It means that you should use `gets_s()` instead of `gets()`
The compiler *usually* knows what's best for the program and what shouldn't be allowed.