# What is the error in using fopen instead of fopen_s as suggested by Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, opengl, fopen

I started working on the OpenGL code for Amusement Park. but I'm getting the following error:

```
"error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details."
```

even if I try to change it frm fopen to `fopen_s`, there more errors.

This is the code part:

```
GLuint LoadBMP(const char *fileName)
{
    FILE *file;
    unsigned char header[54], *data;
    unsigned int dataPos, size, width, height;
    file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    fread(header, 1, 54, file);             //Windows BMP begin with 54 byte header
    dataPos = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);   //dec10, Actual BMP data
    size = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);  //dec34, BMP Size
    width = *(int*)&(header[0x12]); //dec18, Image Width
    height = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);    //dec22, Image Height
    if (size == NULL)
        size = width * height * 3;
    if (dataPos == NULL)
        dataPos = 54;
    data = new unsigned char[size];
    fread(data, 1, size, file);
    fclose(file);
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);             //Generate (allocate) 1 texture name
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);  //Bind the 2D texture

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);  //MAG filter
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);  //MIN filter

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data); //target, level, internalFormat, width, height,border, format, type, data 
    return texture;
}
```

I'm getting error in the `file = fopen` statement.

Help me to find the error in this.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line of code. Apparently you're using some compiler setting that turns warnings into errors, which in turn lets Microsoft's paranoia control how you write code.

Comment: 2 choices: (1) define the macro as show in the error message; or (2) show us the error you get with `fopen_s` (note it takes different parameters and returns an error code).

Comment: @PeteBecker `fopen_s` is C11

Comment: @RichardCritten -- the warning/error is Microsoft.

Comment: Before starting to use the `*_s` functions in C++ you might want to consider [C document N1967](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm) proposing its removal from the next C standard.

Comment: *`fopen_s` is C11*  No, `fopen_s` is from the **optional** Annex K of the C11 standard.  Effectively that has only been implemented by Microsoft - but their implementation doesn't comply with the standards set in Annex K.  So using Microsoft's "safer" functions is doubly non-portable: no one else implemented them, and Microsoft didn't meet the standard anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen_s` is the secure version of `fopen` so if you don't want to use `fopen_s` consider using [_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450423/how-to-use-use-crt-secure-no-warnings) to get rid of that error, since you are using Visual Studio.

Now if you want to use `fopen_s` to correct the error, you have to look at [the documentation of fopen_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx)

**Example of use:**

```
errno_t returnValue = fopen_s(&file, fileName, "r");
```

Comment: It's probably more accurate to say `fopen_s()`  is a part of Microsoft's attempt to [embrace, extend, and extinguish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) portable C code (those are Microsoft's own terms for how to take over a market...). Using `fopen_s()` does not make your code more secure, but it does make your code less portable.  See [**N1967 - Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm)