# Error: result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'char' is always false

Tags: c, char, compare, cs50

I'm working on cs50 pset4 recover, and it's going pretty well. But when I made the if statement that checks if that file is a JPEG, clang started writing some weird error messages. Here's my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *pFile;
  char *buffer = NULL;
  char *filename = NULL;
  // If user didn't print 2 items
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
    return 1;
  }
  // Open the file
  pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  int j = 0;
  // checking the card by 512b chunks

  // loop (i=0,  i++);
  while (5 < 6) {
    int i = 0;
    i++;

    // k=fread (buffer, 512, i, *file);
    int k = fread(buffer, 512, i, pFile);
    // if buffer [0]== 0xff // checking if it's the header. If yes - creating a new jpeg; if not -
    // i++
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff &&
        (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
      // if it's not the first file, we should close the last one

      // sprintf
      sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", 2);
      // FILE = fopen (W)
      pFile = fopen(filename, "w");
      // fwrite (buffer, 512, j, *file1)
      fwrite(buffer, 512, j, pFile);
      // j=j+1
      j = j + 1;
    }
    // if k<512 - end of the loop
    if (k < 512) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't finish it all the rest yet, but I stopped when I saw these error messages:

```c
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    recover.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o recover
recover.c:29:15: error: result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
recover.c:29:36: error: result of comparison of constant 216 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
                         ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
recover.c:29:57: error: result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
                                              ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
3 errors generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'recover' failed
make: *** [recover] Error 1
```

I tried using help50, but this happened:

```c
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    recover.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o recover
recover.c:29:15: error: result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
recover.c:29:36: error: result of comparison of constant 216 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
                         ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
recover.c:29:57: error: result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
                                              ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
3 errors generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'recover' failed
make: *** [recover] Error 1

Asking for help...

recover.c:29:15: error: result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]

Not quite sure how to help, but focus your attention on line 29 of recover.c!
```

And when I try googling it, I just get the answer to the whole problem. I don't know what to do, please help me.

Thanks,
Lost in code:)

Comment: chars go from -128 to 127 (on your compiler).

Comment: Ohhhhh okay but how can I fix this code to make it correct and to make it work? I can't use strings since they  removed the cs50.h "training wheel".

Comment: Why would you want to use `string` if you don't deal with strings? Check your text book for alternative data types of size 1.

Comment: regarding: `char *buffer = NULL;` and `char *filename = NULL;`  assigning/reading anything to where these pointers point (address 0)  is an excellent way to cause a seg fault event. (which you do not want to do)  Suggest:   `#define MAX_BUF_LEN 512`  #define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 30 ....  char buffer[ MAX_BUF_LEN ];` and `char filename[ MAX_FILENAME_LEN ] ;`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s imageFile\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: OT: regarding:  ` while (5 < 6) {
    int i = 0;
    i++;
    int k = fread(buffer, 512, i, pFile`  Much better to use the call to `fread()` to control the while loop.  Do not use the variable `i` for the third parameter.  Suggest: ` while ( fread(buffer, sizeof( buffer ), 1, pFile)  == 1 ) {`

    i++;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` on this implementation ranges from -127 to 127 (the minimum). So comparing it with 216 or 255 is futile. So make it `unsigned char *buffer` that stores at least 0 to 255.

Also,

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

is explanatory: `size_t` is internally `unsigned long` which can store more positive numbers than `int`. So you may theoretically have a int overflow.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Main_types

---

A similar question but my answer is in C++:

- [How do I save recoded data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63352544/how-do-i-save-recoded-data/63354541#63354541)

Comment: I don't really think I have an overflow. From what I can understand of the error messages, it's the part where chars can't be more than 127.

Comment: I only answered what's up with the warnings. I don't claim to fix any bug. \\  If you see the C++ answer, you'll find a vector with reserved space. You just set the storage to null. Where would fread store the data?   \\  I think you should ask a new question trying to fix the newly discovered problem.

Answer (score 1):

declare buffer as uint8_t buffer[512] because no space has been allocated to hold the 512 bytes.
Remember to close files when you have finished with them e.g. fclose(pFile)

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this really is a fatal bug in the code, your suggestion does not answer the question. Your code will provide same warnings.

Comment: Yeah but thanks anyway. I've been trying to figure out how to close the files. Can you tell me how it's done? I would have added a question about it but the topic is too short.

Comment: files opened with `fopen()` are closed with `fclose()`

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

On MSCV compiler i got complaints about

```
 while (5 < 6)
```

on line 23,

> warning C4127: conditional expression is constant

and it is indeed a constant. You can change it

```
        int k = fread(buffer, 512, i, pFile);
```

on line 29,

> conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data

`fread()` returns `size_t` unsigned and `k` is `int` so it can turn to a negative number if `fread()` reads more than `INT_MAX` bytes.

and here we have also

> 'buffer' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for
> the function 'fread'

sure it appears in other parts. You have `buffer` declared as

```
char* buffer = NULL;
```

and never allocated memory for it.

I changed

```
char _buffer[512];
char* buffer = _buffer;
```

and the `while` to

```
while (pFile) // pFile is not 0
```

since `pFile` refers to the open file, it is true

and added a cast to `fread()`

```
int k = (int) fread(buffer, 512, (size_t)i, pFile);
```

so it compiled ok

Comment: I know that it is an infinite loop. If you look next to the bottom of my code, there is a if statement with ```return 1;``` inside it. So once the if statement proves true, it closes the program and finishes the loop.

Comment: This is very very common and I am not discussing it: it is my compiler that is complaining about it and I just told you that you can make any compiler happy by using `while(pFile)` for the same effect, since `pFile` is a handle for an open file and will be as true as `6>5` for the time of your loop