I am a complete beginner to Visual Studio and whenever I try to debug my program it gives me a pop-up window saying it can't find the file specified
As the title suggests I am literally a complete beginner to C and C++ and I have an exam tomorrow that I am trying to prepare for. I have copied and pasted code I know for a fact works in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, and whenever I press Local Windows Debugger first I get a pop-up saying

"There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"

and when I press "Yes" almost instantly I get another pop-up saying

"Unable to start program '[FILE PATH]'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I apologize if I wasn't descriptive enough I literally have no idea what to do.
I tried searching for the file and the file doesn't exist. I also tried changing the Debugging location by going to Project > Properties > Debugging > Command and putting in the location where my project file is saved but then it gives a different pop-up saying "Access denied".
Only errors I get are 2 instances of C4996 even after I write
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
This is the code I'm trying to run (apologies it's not in English, I'm not a native speaker):
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

// Funkcija za izračun površine pravokutnog trokuta
float povrsina_pravokutnog_trokuta(float kateta1, float kateta2) {
    float povrsina = 0.5f * kateta1 * kateta2;
    return povrsina;
}

int main() {
    float kateta1, kateta2;

    // Unos kateta od korisnika
    printf("Unesite duljinu prve katete: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &kateta1) != 1) {
        printf("Neispravan unos.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Unesite duljinu druge katete: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &kateta2) != 1) {
        printf("Neispravan unos.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Provjera jesu li katete pozitivne vrijednosti
    if (kateta1 > 0 && kateta2 > 0) {
        // Izračun i ispis rezultata
        float povrsina = povrsina_pravokutnog_trokuta(kateta1, kateta2);
        printf("Povrsina pravokutnog trokuta je: %.2f\n", povrsina);
    }
    else {
        printf("Katete moraju biti pozitivne vrijednosti.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


If there are build errors you are de facto not debugging the code you just wrote. Fix the build errors first. Look at the error log and output tabs of VS.

"There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?" You need to press No because if you never successfully built your code you can't go back to the working version. This dialog exists basically for the rare situation where you just broke your code and your boss steps in your office asks to see a demo..

Is Visual Studio linked to a C/C++ compiler?

Have you ever build your code at least one time without errors?

Without seeing the error output we can only guess, so here's a few of mine: you accidentally copied smart quotes from your source material; missing }; you did not install the C++ workload for VS; antivirus software ate your .exe; you're using C++ features that are not present in whatever C++ version VS defaults to; no or more than one main function.

The phrase "There were build errors" from the compiler means that you know for a fact that the code doesn't work.

Fix the build errors.  Then the code should compile and link, and you ought to be able to run your program in the debugger.  You need to put _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450838/4641116 (not as a #define)

Please copy and paste the build errors from the Output Tab of Visual Studio. We need the exact text of the errors.

Your code looks 100% c code and not c++ at all. Not sure if msvc compiles c code differently as I don't write c code anymore.

I needed to write
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
above
#include <stdio.h>
instead of the other way around, thank you to everyone who helped!
