# Is there a way to use fopen_s() with GCC or at least create a #define about it?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, fopen

MSVC compiler says that `fopen()` is deprecated, and recommends the use of `fopen_s()`.

Is there any way to use `fopen_s()` and still be portable?

Any ideas for a `#define`?

Comment: A similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386/fopen-deprecated-warning).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Microsoft's `*_s` functions are unportable, I usually use equivalent C89/C99 functions and disable deprecation warnings (`#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE`).

If you insist, you can use an adaptor function (not necessarily a macro!) that delegates `fopen()` on platforms that don't have `fopen_s()`, but you must be careful to map values of `errno_t` return code from `errno`.

```
errno_t fopen_s(FILE **f, const char *name, const char *mode) {
    errno_t ret = 0;
    assert(f);
    *f = fopen(name, mode);
    /* Can't be sure about 1-to-1 mapping of errno and MS' errno_t */
    if (!*f)
        ret = errno;
    return ret;
}
```

However, I fail to see how `fopen_s()` is any more secure than `fopen()`, so I usually go for portability.

Comment: Funny thing is, they are now part of C11 (albeit in the optional Annex K)

Comment: Much better than my (now former, not that I need it anymore) pure macro approach. Your function approach partially reproduces the fopen_s behavior on failure by returning errno (= EINVAL, i.e. 22, fwiw). You could also generate an *invalid parameter exception* to match fopen_s behavior even more closely.

Comment: BTW, according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno), **errno** "expands to a static modifiable lvalue of type int )until to C++11)", and "expands to a thread-local modifiable lvalue of type int (since C++11)." So your return type should be int.

Comment: *Funny thing is, they are now part of C11* [Microsoft's versions are **not** part of Annex K](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm): "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ...  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Answer (score 9):

In C/C++ code,

```
#ifdef __unix
#define fopen_s(pFile,filename,mode) ((*(pFile))=fopen((filename),(mode)))==NULL
#endif
```

In Makefile

```
CFLAGS += -D'fopen_s(pFile,filename,mode)=((*(pFile))=fopen((filename),(mode)))==NULL'
```

Attention that on success fopen_s return 0 while fopen return a nonzero file pointer. Therefore it is necessary to add "==NULL" to the end of macro, e.g.:

```
if (fopen_s(&pFile,filename,"r")) perror("cannot open file");
```

Comment: You missed the part where `fopen_s()` returns `errno` if the `fopen()` fails.

Answer (score 8):

if you are using C11, `fopen_s` is a [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

In `gcc` you need to use `--std=c11` parameter.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `fopen_s()` and other functions in [Annex K of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K) are optional per [**K.2 Scope**, paragraph 1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.2p1): "This annex specifies a series of optional extensions ..."  Effectively, as of 2019 only Microsoft has implemented Annex K, and the Microsoft implementation ["cannot be considered conforming or portable"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm).

Comment: @edj in fact is c11 not c++11 even the parameter to use in gcc. so your comment is not correct.

Comment: @AndrewHenle even if you might be right, the question is directly asking a GCC to use fopen_s. so it might not be the universal solution, but it fit the question, say is wrong is too restrictive, might not be complete. As a per  C language, not neither C ANSI is probably 100% portable in some complex software, too low level. So here goes again: tradeoff.

Comment: @Raffaello GCC has never implemented Annex K, and never will. [Some reasons given as to why](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1106.txt): "Let's vote against that proposal.  It's controversial, arguably
leads to buggier software, and does not reflect the consensus of
the community."

Comment: [There's also this](http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/Implement-C11-annex-K-td279910.html):  "My view is that Annex K was a big mistake -- the latest iteration of
the committee falling for the antics of a "sponsor" that has no
interest in actually implementing the standard and who has done
nothing but try to undermine the C language for the past 20+ years"

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724726/why-didnt-gcc-implement-s-functions among many other questions and answers here that point out the problems with Annex K and its `*_s` "safe" functions.  In short, they're non-portable and the **only** implementation in any real use - Microsoft's - is non-conforming anyway.

Comment: @Raffaello Is fopen_s supported in clang's library, eg will it run on say FreeBSD?

Comment: @Jay as reported already `fopen_s` is not portable or never fully implemented outside the Microsoft world neither in C11. So, unfortunately no, strictly in C is just use `fopen` available

Answer (score 3):

Many of Microsoft's secure functions are included in Annex K of the C11 standard, but it is not widely supported, so portability is still an issue. There is a need for the improved security in some applications; maybe the support will improve in the future.

I the past, I did it like this:

```
  #define fopen_s(fp, fmt, mode)          *(fp)=fopen( (fmt), (mode))
```

The macro is simple and straight forward, good enough for something quick and dirty, but it doesn't provide the exception behavior of fopen_s, and it won't provide the security of the real fopen_s function.

@Alex B's function approach above partially reproduces the proper behavior on failure; he returns errno (= EINVAL). His approach could be extended further by generating an *invalid parameter exception* to more fully reproduce the behavior of fopen_s.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define fopen_s(fp, fmt, mode)  ({\
    *(fp)=fopen( (fmt), (mode));\
    (*(fp) ) ? 0:errno;\
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I just add "({...})" supported by GCC and Clang to return value based on the 2nd floor answer of @riderBill. Thank riderBill.

Answer (score -2):

Accroding to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen 
it's possible to enable *_s functions on the standard library:

> As with all bounds-checked functions, `fopen_s` is only guaranteed to be available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined by the implementation and if the user defines `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to the integer constant `1` before including `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: As the quoted text says, this option is only available if the implementation defines `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`.  Most implementations don't.