# fopen_s not resolved under ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, fopen, readfile

I want to open file so I use fopen_s function under ubuntu. Although I `#include <stdio.h>` as read here http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen, I get error function was not declared in the scope.
Please help me what am I doing wrong, and how to make it run?

```
FILE *fp;
fopen_s(&fp, strFilename.c_str(), "rb");
if (fp == NULL){
    cout << "cannot open " << strFilename.c_str();
    return false;
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Are you compiling with -std=c11?

Comment: Note also that this function is NOT part of the C++11 standard, only C11, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching glibc on Linux finds no evidence that `fopen_s`() is implemented in glibc on Linux.

I find no mention of `fopen_s`() in the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). It appears to me like `fopen_s`() is a non-portable library function that's implemented only on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: thanks for that research, I did just follow tutorial, but indeed it is on windows. Is there any possibility to make the totally same with different funtion?

Comment: It is part of the C11 specification, page 490: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf (with description on page 588)
Obviously, the degree of implementation for C11 on Linux, I can't comment on.

Comment: Use fopen() instead of fopen_s(). I do not see anything that fopen_s() does that cannot be accomplished with fopen().

Answer (score 4):

Try to use fopen()

```
#ifdef __unix
#define fopen_s(pFile,filename,mode) ((*(pFile))=fopen((filename),  (mode)))==NULL
#endif
```

reference: [Is there a way to use fopen_s() with GCC or at least create a #define about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513209/is-there-a-way-to-use-fopen-s-with-gcc-or-at-least-create-a-define-about-it)