# Using fgets to read through file in C

Tags: c, fgets

I am trying to read through the file given then tokenize it. The only problem im having is fgets.The file open recieves no errors. I have seen this elsewhere on the site however no matter how i set this up including setting fileLine to a set amount like (char fileline [200]) i get a segmentation fault. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *fileName = "0";
    char *tokenize, *savePtr;
    struct Record *database= malloc(sizeof(database[0]));
    int recordNum =0;
    char *fileLine = malloc(sizeof(char *));//have replaced with fileline[200] still didnt work
    FILE *fd = open(fileName,O_RDWR);
    if(fd< 0){
        perror("ERROR OPENING FILE");
    }

    while(fgets(fileLine,200,fd) !=NULL){
        printf("%s\n", fileLine);
        tokenize = strtok_r(fileLine,",",&savePtr);
        while(tokenize != NULL){
         //TOKENIZING into a struct
        }
}
```

Comment: you're telling fgets to fetch 200 chars into a string that's been malloced to  be sizeof(*char), e.g. 200 bytes into a **4 BYTE** variable (e.g. size of a pointer to a string). you need `malloc(200 * sizeof(char))`

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` always

Comment: @MarcB even when ive used what you suggested or when ive made it a set array of 200(char fileLine[200];) i still get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @iharob the second while loop is not the issue. i have run this without fgets and it tokenizes properly with a hardcoded fileLine. The issue is at the fgets because i never make it to the printf statement afterword.

Comment: @justin that's just wrong, you can't be sure. Undefined behavior does not always happen the same way, it's undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why use [open()](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:open) with `FILE`? Use [fopen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *fileName = "test.txt";
  char *tokenize, *savePtr;
  char fileLine[200] = {0}; // init this to be NULL terminated
  FILE *fd = fopen(fileName, "r");
  if (fd == 0) { // error check, equal to 0 as iharob said, not less than 0
    perror("ERROR OPENING FILE");
    return -1;
  }

  while (fgets(fileLine, 200, fd) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", fileLine);
    tokenize = strtok_r(fileLine, ",", &savePtr);
    while (tokenize != NULL) {
      tokenize = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &savePtr); // do not forget to pass NULL
      //TOKENIZING into a struct
    }
  }
  fclose(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

As Weather Vane said, `fd < 0` would work if you used `open()`. However, with `fopen()`, you should check to see if the pointer is `NULL`, ecquivalently `fd == 0`.

---

A comparison between this functions that open a file can be found in:

1. [open and fopen function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605848/open-and-fopen-function)
2. [C fopen vs open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open)

The way I have it in mind is that `fopen()` is of higher level.

Comment: Wow, I didn't see that ... note that `fd < 0` would be wrong.

Comment: Note: OP is using `open`, not `fopen`. So `fd < 0` would have been OK, but he wrote `*fd = open()`

Comment: @WeatherVane of course, but now we used `fopen()`. However, I should clear it up, editing..

Comment: Agreed @AlterMann, edited, thanks! I could also get rid of `stdlib` too I guess.

Comment: Note: The ` = {0}` in `char fileLine[200] = {0};` is not needed for this code.  Not a _bad_ thing to do either.

Comment: @chux if nothing is read by `fgets()`, then `fileLine` will be left unchanged and I wouldn't like to see it uninitialized later, but I see your point.

Comment: "if nothing is read by fgets(), then fileLine will be left unchanged" does not always agree with the C spec for `fgets()`.  "If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are indeterminate and a null pointer is returned." §7.21.7.2

Comment: I am not talking about an error @chux. From the ref, "If this happens before any characters could be read, the pointer returned is a null pointer (and the contents of str remain unchanged)."

Comment: @G. Samaras I take it your reference is not from a C spec.

Comment: @chux I am copy pasted from this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: I see the quote also says "If a read error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a null pointer is also returned (but the contents pointed by str may have changed)."  Even though you might not be talking about an error, I see no way to prevent `fgets()` from responding to errors with an indeterminate buffer.

Comment: Me neither @chux, thanks for the nice discussion. :)

Comment: Don't forget to call `fclose(fd);` afterwards.

Comment: @scai tnx, answer updated, hope you agree now.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
char *fileLine = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

allocates memory for a `char *` type, 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the platform).

So when you do

```
fgets(fileLine,200,fd)
```

it expects there to be 200 bytes of memory available.

Try this:

```
char *fileLine = malloc(200);
if (fileLine == NULL) { ... }   // check for error
```

which will allocate the memory required.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `open()` instead of `fopen()`.

You can't be sure that the file did open correctly because `fopen()` does not return an integer, but a pointer to a `FILE *` object, on failure it returns `NULL`, so the right codition is

```
FILE *file;

file = fopen(filename, "r");
if (file == NULL)
 {
    perror("fopen()");
    return -1;
 }
```

In your code, you still go and use `fgets()` even when the `fopen()` fails, you should abort the program in that case.

Also, `malloc()` takes the number of bytes as the size parameter, so if you want `fgets()` to be limited to read just `count` bytes, then `malloc()` should be

```
char  *buffer;
size_t count;

count  = 200; /* or a value obtained someway */
buffer = malloc(count);
if (buffer == NULL)
 {
    fclose(file);
    perror("malloc()");
    return -1;
 }
```

All the problems in your code would be pointed out by the compiler if you enable compilation warnings.