# Can I get access to the file descriptor underlying a std::[io]fstream?

Tags: c++, locking, std, fstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)

I need access to the file descriptor so that I can use the flock() (or fcntl(), I don't care) system call to create and release advisory file locks.  But I couldn't see any way to get at it.  Nor any alternative approaches that didn't smell of a horrible hack.

Any suggestion?  Am I missing an obvious way to implement file locking?

Comment: In a word, no. GCC used to provide a way, but the feature was removed some 10 years ago and AFAICT there are no plans to put it back.

Comment: There's certainly no portable way to do this. The `basic_filebuf` that is a member of the `fstream` probably contains a `FILE *`, but there is no (portable) way to get at it.

Comment: Unfortunate.  I am using boost::serialization; input/output archives need [io]fstreams to their constructors.  But in order to provide the opportunity of correct operation, I had hoped to use flock/fcntl on the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: You can use `boost::stream` instead of `std::stream` for serialization. You can also write your own `streambuf` exposing the file descriptor (not very hard to do).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I cannot get access to the underlying file descriptor in a [io]fstream.  Nor do there seem to be c'tors that will let me build an [io]fstream from an existing file descriptor.  This approach to my locking problem is apparently infeasible.

I have found another workable solution to my locking problem, however: I will use the boost::interprocess synchronization mechanisms (in particular, a boost::interprocess::sharable_lock) to achieve the same end.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.sharable_upgradable_mutexes.sharable_upgradable_locks

After I have implemented this, I will report back the ease/difficulty, and additional pointers.

Comment: You can build an iostream from an existing file descriptor with [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/file_descriptor.html#file_descriptor)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reverting to the C world, use `<mutex>` and any other threading functionality available in C++. If you don't have access to a C++11 compiler, time to upgrade.

Comment: Looked at that, but seems to have several problems.  First, there does not seem to be any option for shareable/exclusive semantics (as there is with flock/fcntl).  I could easily enough invent this, but I am lazy...  The second problem is that it doesn't seem to offer cross-process semantics, which was the whole point of using it.

Answer (score -1):

[How do I lock files using fopen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573282/how-to-lock-files-in-c-c-using-fopen)

I believe this question shows you how to use flock() (look at the first answer). Note that the only reason this is an answer, not a comment, is because I can't find the comment button :)

Comment: You cannot portably get a `FILE*` from a `std::fstream`.