# How to open a file and lock it in C?

Tags: c, winapi

If I open a file using the following code:

```
FILE *file = fopen("D:\\1.mp4", "rb");
```

This will not lock the file, so for example I can open this file using Notepad and write to it!

So is there a way I can make sure that no other application is allowed to write to this file, or should I use WinAPI to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you looking for a [tag:winapi] solution, or a [tag:c] solution?

Comment: @Amit I am looking for a C solution, but if there is none, then I will use WinAPI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, there apparently isn't a way to do this, although POSIX has some ways to do that. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573282/how-to-lock-files-in-c-c-using-fopen) for details.

In WINAPI, it's rather simple to do with [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) (but you end up with a Windows Handle, not a `FILE` pointer):

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("D:\\1.mp4", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the function parameters be like this: `HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("D:\\1.mp4", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);`?

Comment: Note you can use `_open_osfhandle` followed by `_fdopen` to obtain a `FILE*` from a `HANDLE`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter you're right, but it's easier to use `_fsopen` as noted by Joni. The same "problem" remains though, this is not standard C and no longer standard WINAPI (such that could be transported to non C domain)

Answer (score 4):

The windows feature you want to use is the "sharing mode." You can set it using the [`_fsopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db.aspx) function. To deny write access use `_SH_DENYWR` as the third parameter.

Comment: That's a great answer, but it's neither standard C, nor is it winapi. It's "the best of both worlds" while not being either of them :-)