# Reading Serial Port Data

Tags: c, file-io, serial-port, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to read in serial port data in C on Mac OS. Configuration of serial port is done in separate Arduino IDE.

I am able to read partial data, but then the printed data repeats itself and starts reading zeros as seen below. If I remove O_NONBLOCK, the program just hangs. What can I do to fix this problem? Secondly, given that I am reading in data in a for loop, how do I make sure the read rate corresponds with the baud rate?

Seen data: 
296 310 0

320 295 311

320 295 311

9 296 311

320 295 311

320 295 311

9 296 311

...

0 0 0

0 0 0

0 0 0
etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int buffer[300];

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    // open serial port
    int port;
    port = open("/dev/tty.usbmodem1411", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (port == -1)
    {
        printf("Unable to open serial port.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // instantiate file
    FILE* file = fdopen(port, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to instantiate file.\n");
        close(port);
        return 2;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
    {

        fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &buffer[3*i], &buffer[3*i+1], &buffer[3*i+2]);
        printf("%d %d %d\n", buffer[3*i], buffer[3*i+1], buffer[3*i+2]);

        i = (i + 1) % 100;

        usleep(10000);

    }

    fclose(file);
    close(port);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: 1) You will probably get better results with the /dev/cu.usbmodem#### devices than the tty ones.  2) Make sure you check the return value of fscanf and only process the data if it is successful

Comment: More fundamentally, I don't believe fscanf will "rewind" the input stream if it runs when only a partial message has arrived, so you may need something which collects complete messages, if you can't afford to drop data if you call fscanf with only a partial message received.  Consider instead a blocking fgets() to get an entire line to a buffer, and then sscanf() the buffer to recover your fields.

Comment: By process data do you mean storing in the buffer array that I have? In that case, should I have an additional buffer array, and if fscanf returns less than three, skip? I would prefer a complete message, so I can afford skipping the partial message if fscanf returns less than three.

Comment: No, store the character array (ie, string) data as it arrives, until you have an entire line to parse.  Otherwise you will loose data if you call fscanf() with an incomplete line received.  Or else write a parser which can handle characters dripping in one at a time and parse them to numbers.  You have been neglecting to consider that there can be mid-line delays in receiving the data, and that your current attempts to parse it are entirely asynchronous, so you'll occasionally try to do so at unworkable times and lose data.

Comment: This is what I came up with - how do I get fgets to check for partial data? Or is that already done with the first condition?               `if (fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), file) != NULL)
   {         
   sscanf(temp, "%d %d %d\n", &buffer[3*i], &buffer[3*i+1], &buffer[3*i+2]);
            printf("%d %d %d\n", buffer[3*i], buffer[3*i+1], buffer[3*i+2]);
    }`

Comment: `i` declaration is not shown.  Please show.  Is it initialized? If not, _that_ is a problem.

Comment: Check the result of `fscanf()` as in `if (3 != fscanf(...)) Handle_error();`

Answer (score 0):

For Chris Stratton:

```
if (fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), file) != NULL) 
{ 
     sscanf(temp, "%d %d %d\n", &buffer[3*i], &buffer[3*i+1], &buffer[3*i+2]); 
     printf("%d %d %d\n", buffer[3*i], buffer[3*i+1], buffer[3*i+2]); 
}
```

However, going back to my original question, even if I'm using fscanf and printf, I obtain data, and then I only read zeros indefinitely. I'm thinking this might be more of a serial port communication issue?

Comment: You still aren't checking the return vale of fscanf()  and at this point it would be a good idea to print the raw received buffers (before parsing) for debugging.  Also, you need to use this in a blocking manner, so get rid of the O_NONBLOCK.

Comment: If I get rid of O_NONBLOCK the program hangs unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, it should, until it sees the newline at the end of a line of data.  If you wanted to run in non-blocking mode, you would probably have to write you own logic to collect and reassemble buffers and find newlines that are not at the end of a buffer, unless you read only one character at a time in your buffer and stop and parse when you get a newline.  Also, have your remembered to switch from the tty device to the cu device yet?

Comment: So if the line port= open( ...) hangs, how do I fix that? Also, in reference to your first comment to this answer, I am not using fscanf anymore. Lastly, I tried cu device and there was no improvement over tty.