# PyPy file append mode

Tags: python, pypy

I have code like this:

```
f1 = open('file1', 'a')
f2 = open('file1', 'a')

f1.write('Test line 1\n')
f2.write('Test line 2\n')
f1.write('Test line 3\n')
f2.write('Test line 4\n')
```

When this code is run with standard Python 2.7 interpreter, the file contains four lines as expected. However, when I run this code under PyPy, the file contains only two lines.

Could someone explain the differences between Python and PyPy in working with files in append mode?

**UPDATED**: The problem doesn't exist in the PyPy 2.3.

Comment: Why would you ever open the same file with two different handles?

Comment: I have code like this in the old code, which hard to change. With standart Python this code works, but not with PyPy.

Comment: it is a matter of buffering and flushing the content of the file. on PyPy, the committing of the file is delayed, and therefore the last handle to commit to the file replaces its entire content.

Comment: [pypy bug](https://bugs.pypy.org/issue1739)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason in different behavior is different implementation of file I/O operations.

CPython [implements](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1bc0a8310b9f/Objects/fileobject.c#l1852) it's file I/O on top of `fopen`, `fread` and `fwrite` functions from `stdio.h` and is working with `FILE *` streams.

In the same time PyPy [implements](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/17a4ad744f46b213f56a7392fc5da882a71dce78/rpython/rlib/streamio.py?at=default#cl-326) it's file I/O on top of POSIX `open`, `write` and `read` functions and is working with `int` file descriptors.

Compare these two programs in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *a = fopen("file1", "a");
    FILE *b = fopen("file1", "a");

    fwrite("Test line 1\n", 12, 1, a);
    fflush(a);
    fwrite("Test line 2\n", 12, 1, b);
    fflush(b);
    fwrite("Test line 3\n", 12, 1, a);
    fflush(a);
    fwrite("Test line 4\n", 12, 1, b);

    fclose(a);
    fclose(b);

    return 0;
}
```

and

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int a = open("file1", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
    int b = open("file1", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);

    write(a, "Test line 1\n", 12);
    write(b, "Test line 2\n", 12);
    write(a, "Test line 3\n", 12);
    write(b, "Test line 4\n", 12);

    close(a);
    close(b);

    return 0;
}
```

More info on difference between `open` and `fopen` you could find in answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open).

**UPDATE**:

After inspecting PyPy codebase some more, it seems to me it [doesn't use `O_APPEND` flag](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/341e1e3821fff77db3bb5cdb7a4851626298c44e/pypy/rlib/streamio.py?at=release-1.9#cl-53) by some reason, but `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT` for "a" mode. So it is the real reason in PyPy you need to `seek` to the end of file after each `write` call, as J.F. Sebastian mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156116/pypy-file-append-mode/23163051#23163051). I guess a bug should be created at PyPy bugtracker, as `O_APPEND` flag is available both on Windows and Unix. So, what PyPy does now looks like:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int a = open("file1", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
    int b = open("file1", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);

    write(a, "Test line 1\n", 12);
    write(b, "Test line 2\n", 12);
    write(a, "Test line 3\n", 12);
    write(b, "Test line 4\n", 12);

    close(a);
    close(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Without O_APPEND flag it should reproduce PyPy behavior.

Comment: You have to wonder if PyPy is adhering to the spec or if the spec is not specific enough in this case.

Comment: @wheaties I don't think that there is a such specification, it is implementation specific. CPython documents that it's [File Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) are implemented on top of `stdio.h`. In the same time it has [io](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) module [implemented](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c776ed8a8e75/Modules/_io/fileio.c) on top of POSIX functions.

Comment: Note: CPython 3 also implements I/O on top of POSIX `open`, `write`, `read`.  It is accessable as `io` module in Python 2.7

Comment: On my machine both your C programs, Python 2, Python 3, Jython produce the same output despite different I/O implementations. Only Pypy differs

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian There was an issue on my system, which lead to incorrect interpretation of running my C code. It seems to me, I've found now a real bug in implementation and added another C code example to reproduce it.

Comment: your C code is missing `lseek(fd, 0, 2)` after the `open()` if you want to make it like Pypy. As [I said in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23163051/4279) POSIX `O_APPEND` behaviour is not mandated by Python docs i.e., it is not clear whether the Pypy behaviour is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

[On POSIX systems](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html):

> O_APPEND
>       If set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file
>   prior to each write.

It means that if a file is opened in "append" mode then when its buffer is flushed; the content shall go to the end of the file.

Python 2, Python 3, Jython respect that on my machine. In your case, the content is smaller than the file buffer therefore you see all writes from one file followed by all writes from another file in the result on the disk.

It is easier to understand if the files are line-buffered:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

filename = 'file1'
with open(filename, 'wb', 0) as file:
    pass # truncate the file

f1 = open(filename, 'a', 1)
f2 = open(filename, 'a', 1)

f1.write('f1 1\n')
f2.write('f2 aa\n')
f1.write('f1 222\n')
f2.write('f2 bbbb\n')
f1.write('f1 333\n')
f2.write('f2 cc\n')
```

#### Output

```
f1 1
f2 aa
f1 222
f2 bbbb
f1 333
f2 cc
```

Python documentation does not mandate such behaviour. [It just mentions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> ..'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems means that **all writes append to the end of
>   the file regardless of the current seek position**)<sup>emphasize is mine</sup>

Pypy produces the following output in unbuffered and line-buffered mode:

```
f2 aaff2 bbbf1f2 cc
```

Manually moving the file position to the end fixes pypy output:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import os

filename = 'file1'
with open(filename, 'wb', 0) as file:
    pass # truncate the file

f1 = open(filename, 'a', 1)
f2 = open(filename, 'a', 1)

f1.write('f1 1\n')
f2.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
f2.write('f2 aa\n')
f1.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
f1.write('f1 222\n')
f2.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
f2.write('f2 bbbb\n')
f1.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
f1.write('f1 333\n')
f2.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
f2.write('f2 cc\n')
```

If the file is fully-buffered then add `.flush()` after each `.write()`.

It is probably not a good idea to write to the same file using more than one file object at once.