# Multiple File Handles for the Same File

Tags: python, python-2.7

So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156116/pypy-file-append-mode) got me thinking.  I did some testing with multiple file handles for the same file, and found some odd results that I was hoping someone could explain.

```
>>> f1 = open("test.txt",'w')
>>> f1.close()
>>> f1, f2 = open("test.txt", 'w'), open("test.txt", 'w')
>>> f1 == f2
False
>>> f1, f2 = open("test.txt", 'r'), open("test.txt", 'r')
>>> f1 == f2
False
```

Why do these tests not return `True`?  Surely assigning a handle to the same file should have the same value.

What's the underlying mechanism for these comparisons to return `False` and what is the rationale for creating this behavior?

Comment: I think the 'f1 == f2' is simply comparing the object 'f1' and 'f2' and they are definitely not the same, isn't it?

Comment: `Surely assigning a handle to the same file should have the same value.` No. Why?

Comment: @njzk2, because the return of the ```open()``` function is the same object

Comment: `the same object` as you have pointed out yourself, not it is not the same object (since `f1 == f2 -> False`)

Comment: You new example just show that '6 == 6', and it is true, of course. But it has nothing to do with your first example.

Comment: @njzk2, right, yes, the observed behavior tells me they are not, but its not what I expected so I'm looking for an explanation as to why

Comment: @JerryMeng, hmm, yeah, not a good example

Comment: two handles opened on a file are different. they may point to different places of the file (in your `r` example, try to read from f1 and from f2, you'll read the same line twice, showing that f1 has advanced in the file, but f2 has not).

Comment: So basically, you create TWO objects independently. The only reason you may think they are same (they are not for real) is that they are the handler for same file. However, it makes no differences. We are talking about the objects (everything in Python is Object) rather than what those objects are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying mechanism is explained here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

> some types (for example, file objects) support only a degenerate notion of comparison where any two objects of that type are unequal
>
> ...
>
> Non-identical instances of a class normally compare as non-equal unless the class defines the **eq**() method or the **cmp**() method.