# Check if two file pointers point to same file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, file-pointer

How do I check if two file pointers point to the same file or not.

```
>>> fp1 = open("/data/logs/perf.log", "r")
>>> fp1
<open file '/data/logs/perf.log', mode 'r' at 0x7f5adc07cc00>
>>> fp2 = open("/data/logs/perf.log", "r")
>>> fp2
<open file '/data/logs/perf.log', mode 'r' at 0x7f5adc07cd20>
>>> fp1 == fp2
False
>>> fp1 is fp2
False
```

My **use case** is I am watching a file for changes and doing something, but logback rolls over this file to old date and creates a new file. But the file pointer variable in python is still pointing to the old file. If `fp1 != fp2`, I would like to update `fp1` to new file.

Why `.name` doesn't work?
When I tried,

```
mv /data/logs/perf.log /data/logs/perfNew.log
echo abctest >> /data/logs/perfNew.log
```

even then the name still is the old one.

```
>>> fp1.readline()
'abctest\n'
>>> fp1.name
'/data/logs/perf.log'
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156274/multiple-file-handles-for-the-same-file

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Question seems related but there is no accepted answer, and doesn't solve my use case.

Comment: @OptimusPrime There is an accepted answer claiming that you *cannot use comparison for file handles*. That is how I read it anyway.

Comment: I could have closed as duplicate and I didn't. Hence _related_ not duplicate. The fstat answer below works (beat me by a few minutes damn :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry, misread your comment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`os.fstat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fstat) is available on Windows and UNIX, and comparing the inode number (file serial number) and device ID [uniquely identify a file within the system](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html):

```
import os
fp1 = open("/data/logs/perf.log", "r")
fp2 = open("/data/logs/perf.log", "r")
stat1 = os.fstat(fp1.fileno())
stat2 = os.fstat(fp2.fileno())

# This comparison tests if the files are the same
stat1.st_ino == stat2.st_ino and stat1.st_dev == stat2.st_dev

fp1.close()
fp2.close()
```

`st_ino` is the inode number which identifies the file uniquely on a drive. However, the same inode number can exist on different drives, which is why the `st_dev` (device ID) is used to distinguish which drive/disk/device the file is on.

Comment: Please close `fp1` and `fp2` ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil Isn't it okay if I just close one?

Comment: @OptimusPrime: No, you need to make sure every file handle is closed.