# Open() syscall filedesriptor

Tags: c++, operating-system, system-calls

I have to correct the return value of the `open()` syscall of a posix OS. I understood from the *man-Pages*  that it has to return the *file descriptor*, and , in case of an error the system call will return -1 and set the *`errno`* value. The problem is that I do not know how to get the *file descriptor* for the opened nod. I checked  all the files and didn't found a method that can assign a *fd* to processes.

Here is the method :

```
    int syscalls::open(const char *path, int oflags, mode_t mode){

    syscall_message msg;

    msg.call.type = syscalls::open_call;
    msg.open_data.path_name = &path[0];
    msg.open_data.flags = oflags;
    msg.open_data.create_mode = mode;

    syscaller::call_system(msg);

    return msg.error.number;
}
```

`syscall_message` is a struct that holds  the data info for the system call. `syscalls` is the `namesapace` where all the system calls are. `syscaller` is used to send the call to the kernel, unsing the `call_system` method.

The `call_system` method:

```
syscalls::open_call:
        {
            //get the file
            i_fs_node_ptr file = i_fs::open_node( msg.open_data.path_name );

            //add the file handle
            if ( file )
            {
                cur_process->push_filehandle(
                        file,
                        msg.open_data.flags,
                        msg.open_data.create_mode );
            }
            else
            {
                msg.error.type = syscalls::e_no_such_entry;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What are `syscall_message`, `syscalls`, and `syscaller`? Are they part of some library or framework you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "I can't get the file descriptor". As you have mentioned open() returns it. It's simply stored in an integer variable. If this variable is equal to -1, then something has gone wrong. For example if you have

```
int file = open(path, O_SYNC, O_DIRECT, O_RDONLY);
```

but you do not have the reading permissions for the file named **path** the variable **file** will get a value of -1. Additional manipulation on an opened file can be done via **read()** (if file was opened in read mode) and **write()** (if file was opened in write mode). I suggest you read the [documentation on the open() function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) more carefully. If you need more control over the file descriptor I suggest you use **fopen()**:

- [Discussion on the difference between open() and fopen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open)
- [Tutorial on fopen()](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html)
- [Documentation on fopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

Comment: Yes, but I am  referring to the way that  `open()` system call woks. The method I posted is the `open()` system call for a Posix OS. The call sends the data need for opening a file to the kernel trough `call_system()`. After `call_system(msg)` does its magic and the file is or is not opened I have to return the `fd` of that file, or -1 in case of an error. Now, `msg` holds the data that the kernel uses to open a new nod. but after the node is opens it doesn't set a file descriptor for that nod. I will post the `call_system()` method.