# Is fopen() unsuitable for serial port?

Tags: c, serial-port, fopen, file-descriptor

I tried to open serial port via `fopen("serial port path", "+w")`

And get the file descriptor by `fileno()`.

After that, i call `tcsetattr()` but it generate an error showing `Inappropriate ioctl for device` (`perror()` print the error message)

I Know i can just use `open()` but `fopen()` and it was working with same code.

But i am curious what is a problem.

```
FILE* file = fopen("serialDevice", "w+");

fd = fileno(file);
if(fd < 0){
    perror("fileno error");
}
struct termios conf;

//setting conf.....

if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &conf) != 0){
    perror("tcsetattr() failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of `fopen()`? The `fileno(3)` man page indicates that `fileno()` never fails (and doesn't set `errno`).

Comment: you did not mention which OS, even so, I would expect the 'serialDevice' is not a valid path name.  For Linux it would be something llike '/dev/USBtty0' and for windows it would be something like: 'com4'

Comment: in general, a call to tcgetattr() should be first, to retrieve/save the original port settings so they can be restored before exiting the program

Comment: My OS is `ubuntu 12.04` and `serialDevice` is just to describe simply, i used proper device name so that it was working if i use `open()` with the same code.

Comment: Run both versions under `strace` and see where the behavior diverges. This should reveal the cause.

Answer (score -3):

The only difference between open and fopen relevant to your question is that fopen does buffering by default. This *may* be your issue.

You can try disabling the buffer and see if it helps, add: `setbuf(f, NULL);` after you fopen the file and see if it helps.

Comment: No, this is glossing over a lot of more important differences.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the comment, can you explain which other differences that are relevant to this question exist?

Comment: Okay, just did some more research... You seem to be wrong R, I refer you to the following resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C/Q_20905306.html
http://www.unix.com/programming/16622-fopen-open.html

Comment: ...And it made me even more sure that the issue is indeed the buffering

Comment: "Buffering" is not a mode on the open file. It's a layer that only comes into play if you actually use the stdio functions on the `FILE*` to access the file rather than using the file descriptor. I see no way "buffering" could be relevant to OP's question.

Comment: Please provide references that support your claim.