# If a certain word exists in the .txt file, copy that word to another txt file

Tags: c, file

TODO: If a certain word exists in the .txt file, copy that word to another txt file

PROBLEM: It won't write the word after it is found in "from.txt" to "to.txt".

ERROR:

This line: `while ((fscanf(ifp, "%s", line)) != EOF)`

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX_LINE 256

void main()
{
    FILE *ifp;
    FILE *ofp;
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    char word[MAX_LINE];
    if ((ifp = open("from.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open input file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((ofp = open("to.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open output file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter your word: ");
    gets(word);
    while ((fscanf(ifp, "%s", line)) != EOF)
    {
        if (strcmp(line, word) == 0)
        {
            fputs(line, ofp);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It won't write the word after it is found to "to.txt".

Comment: @user3121023 Don't worry about gets/fgets, VS13 is suited perfectly to use gets appropriately. (On a side note, it didn't help)

Comment: @user3121023 Still same error.

Comment: from.txt "blabal reality sdfsdfsd sdfsd a", I try "a", "reality". and btw, I dragged those 2 .txt files into the project (and also to the folder project) @user3121023

Comment: can't open input file , is the output now. @user3121023

Comment: @user3121023 I guess. I also tried with "C:\from.txt"
already.

Comment: @user3121023 Wrote a program to write into "to123.txt" file. it created the file in the directory, and I copied there the 2 files, and now the program works. the solution also was to find the correct directory. Problem solved.

Comment: [`int main`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Please compile with **warnings** enabled.

Comment: You are using `strcmp` to find a single word with a line.  Would `strstr` be a better fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PROBLEM: It won't write the word after it is found in "from.txt" to "to.txt".*

As noted in comments and other answers, *[and for other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658517/645128)*, `open()` may not be the best choice for writing strictly ANSI portable code.

But this is not the reason for the stated problem.

The function `strcmp(...)` is not doing what is needed.
In this line:

```
if (strcmp(line, word) == 0)
```

A single word is being compared with the entire line. And the single word is never identified.  Even if the line in the file *appears* to have only a single word, white space, such as a space, tab or new line character ( " ". \n, \t) would cause the two arguments of `strcmp` to be unequal.

*[strcmp(string1, string2)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)*  possible return values are:
Positive integer when string1 is *greater* than string2
Zero when string1 is *equal* to string2
Negative integer when string1 is *less than* string2

The function `strstr` would be a better fit.  Change the *strcmp* line to use *strstr* :

```
if (strstr(line, word)){...
```

*[strstr(...)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)* looks for the existence of a sub-string within a string.  And, with the other changes that have been discussed, made your code do as you described it should.

Comment: Thank you very much ryyker. This was very useful!!

Answer (score 3):

You are using a wrong API for opening a file. API which you use -- `open` -- is for low-level, descriptor based access. You'll get an `int` value out of it, and `ifp` and `ofp` won't be correct.

You must use a stream based API, called `fopen`. It returns a pointer to the `FILE` structure, which in turn you can pass to `fscanf()` etc.

**Very important**: compile this program with all compiler warnings and observe the output. I'm pretty sure you're getting a log of warning messages from the compiler already.

Comment: Well, now it says I can't open the file.

Comment: You didn't post much about where/how you compile it. With ``fopen("file.txt", "r")`` it expects you have ``file.txt`` in the very same directory from which you run the program. Otherwise you must specify literal path, e.g.: ``/path/to/file.txt``.

Comment: Wrote a program to write into "to123.txt" file. it created the file in the directory, and I copied there the 2 files, and now the program works. the solution also was to find the correct directory. Problem solved.

Comment: To create the output file if it doesn't exist or truncate it and overwrite it if it does exist, for the ``fopen`` on ``ofp`` use ``w+`` mode specifier. You can also make this program better by accepting ``argv`` and passing the paths to the files from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX_LINE 256

void main()
{
FILE *ifp;
FILE *ofp;
char line[MAX_LINE];
char word[MAX_LINE];
//**************************************************************** it's      fopen not open   ***********************************************************
if ((ifp = fopen("from.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Can't open input file.");
    exit(1);
}
if ((ofp = fopen("to.txt", "w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Can't open output file.");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Enter your word: ");
gets(word);
while ((fscanf(ifp, "%s", line)) != EOF)
{
    if (strcmp(line, word) == 0)
    {
        fputs(line, ofp);
        break;
    }
}
fclose(ifp);
fclose(ofp);
getch();
}
```

its working fine ...