# What is the relation between fopen and open?

Tags: c, permissions, fopen, file-descriptor, read-write

I am working on a project for a class and we were given a .c file containing the following code:

```
int fd = -1;
if (fd < 0)
{
  fd = open ("my_dev", O_RDWR);
  if (fd < 0)
  {
    perror ("open");
    return -1;
  }
...
```

So I understand that it is trying to open a file "my_dev" with read/write permissions, and then is returning the file descriptor on success or a negative value on failure, but what I dont understand is why it is giving me "permission denied" consistently. I tried to use this code:

```
int des = open("my_dev", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777);
...
close(des)
```

to open/create the file (this is called before the other block), but this does not work, and yet if I just use this instead:

```
FILE* file = fopen("my_dev","w+");
fprintf(file,str);
fclose(file);
```

I can write to the file, meaning I have write permissions. Now normally, I would just use fopen and fprintf for everything, but for this project, we sort of have to use the teacher's .c file which is going to try to use

```
 open()
```

which is going to give a "permission denied" error which is in turn going to screw up my code.

I guess my question is how fopen and open relate to each other? Everyone seems to be able to recite that open is a system call whereas fopen is a standard lib function, but I cant seem to find a clear answer for how I can create a file with fopen() that can be opened by open() without a "permission denied" error, or how I can create a file with open() which I can then write to, close and open again with open().

In short, how do I create a file in C that I can write to and open later with open(O_RDWR)?

Sorry if this is a little piecey, im super tired.

PS: It should be noted that I am compiling and running on a university computer, so permissions may be "weird" BUT it should be noted that if I create the file with the terminal command "dd" open() will work, and furthermore, I clearly have SOME write permissions since I can indeed write to the file with fopen and fprintf

Comment: Depending on operating system there may not be any relationship between those functions, other than both open files.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fopen` is a library function that provided by the standard C runtime, it returns a stream and you can call stream functions on it, like `fscanf`, `fprintf`, or `fread`, `fwrite`.

`open` is usually a system call on unix-like systems, provided by the operating system kernel, it returns an file descriptor, you can call IO functions with the fd, like `read`, `write`.

Generally `fopen` is implemented using `open` underline.

If you want to use standard stream functions on a file descriptor, you can use the posix api, `fdopen`, which takes a fd, and returns a `FILE*` stream.

Comment: I also tried FILE* file = fdopen(des,"w+") which cannot even write to the file, apparently.

Comment: The des needs to be in O_WRONLY or O_RDWR before calling this.

Comment: AFAIK if you use `C` the `open` is a library function too.

Comment: This all depends on the platform and the implementation, for example, glibc provides wrappers for many system calls, otherwise you would be calling something like syscall(SYS_OPEN, "file", mode)