# fopen vs open (in C) in POSIX

Tags: c, io, posix, fopen

After this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open) , a doubt comes up:

Once *fopen()* is faster than *open()* (for sequential writing/ready operations at least), the former is a library and the latter is a system call, what system call does *fopen()* do in a POSIX compilant OS?

Comment: It depends on the implementation, but usually `fopen` ends up calling `open`.

Comment: I peeked at glibc and it would seem that it _maybe_ uses `mmap` depending on use-case.

Comment: @Lundin But to call `mmap` it has to call `open` first (except maybe for `open_memstream`, but that's a totally different scenario)

Comment: @zwol I only took a brief glance at the code but there were different use-cases for read-only etc.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, all I'm saying is that _whatever_ it conditionally uses `mmap` for, that must be as an alternative to `read`/`write`, not `open`.

Comment: `fopen()` is certainly not faster than `open()` (probably much slower as it has to set up buffering) but it may result in faster I/O later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It calls `open`.

`fopen` itself is not faster than `open`; it can't be, it's `open` plus some extra work.  The performance benefit, described in the linked question, is from the "buffering" done by the `FILE` object over its entire lifecycle.  The actual optimization is to call the `write` primitive *fewer times*, providing *more data* each time.

Here is a simple way to demonstrate the effect: Compile this program.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) return 1;
    long count = atol(argv[1]);
    long chunk = atol(argv[2]);
    if (count < 1 || chunk < 0) return 1;

    FILE *sink = fopen("/dev/null", "wb");
    if (!sink) return 1;

    if (chunk) {
        char *buf = malloc(chunk);
        if (!buf) return 1;
        if (setvbuf(sink, buf, _IOFBF, chunk)) return 1;
    } else {
        if (setvbuf(sink, 0, _IONBF, 0)) return 1;
    }

    while (count--) putc_unlocked('.', sink);
    return 0;
}
```

It takes two arguments: the total number of bytes to write, and the size of the output buffer, in that order.  Run it with various values of both parameters and time its performance; you should see that, e.g.

```
./a.out $((1024*1024*128)) 1
```

is much slower than

```
./a.out $((1024*1024*128)) 8192
```

The first number will need to be quite large for the difference to be measurable.  Once you've played around with that for a while, run

```
strace ./a.out 50 1
```

and

```
strace ./a.out 50 50
```

to understand the difference in what's going on at the system call level.  (If you are using an OS other than Linux, replace `strace` with whatever the equivalent command is for that OS.)

Comment: Additionally, using the stdio functions other than `fopen()` is not *inherently* faster than using the POSIX I/O functions.  One can perform one's own buffering with the latter, for example, and possibly even tune that better to the use case at hand.  But the stdio functions certainly do hide a significant amount of low-level detail, and moreover, provide a well tested implementation of those details.

Comment: In my system, 1 minute and 20,0762 seconds against  0.762 seconds. About 106 times slower!