# vs2012+opencv error C4996: 'cv::flann::Index_<T>'

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

In the vs2012, I run my program, it will tips `error C4996: 'cv::flann::Index_<T>'`.
But in the vs2010, it is Warning.

Could anybody tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: is this the whole error Message?

Comment: yes..only this error Message.

Answer (score 0):

I know `C4996` as a [compiler warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that declares that something is deprecated. But i don´t know if this is the case here because i only encountered it as a warning and not as an error.

You could however try to use `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` in your code, as suggested in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14448455/2927205).